# Passing multiple pieces of data in one submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a data table that has a list of entities on a website. The list has 'action' buttons like 'edit', 'delete' and 'enable/disable' (it's a toggle button, but that really doesn't matter here). The edit button is actually a link pretending to be a button, so let's discount that, but the delete and enable buttons need to pass back to a script exactly what needs deleting or enabling. And this ideally needs to be under one 'action' parameter. There is one `<form>` that encompasses the entire table.

In the following code I'm very much paraphrasing my actual code, and I do use a PHP framework and template engine normally. However, for the purposes of these examples I'll use as plain PHP as possible. (This question is not directly related to PHP though, it's very much HTML and forms.)

Here's an example of a row in my data table:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
        <button type="submit" name="delete" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So now I need to add an enable button:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $item->id; ?>">Edit</a>
        <button type="submit" name="enable" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></button>
        <button type="submit" name="delete" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

At this point, my script that handles this is looking like it's going to end up with lots of `if (isset($_POST['delete']))` type lines, as I'll need a new one for each action, so I think I'll send the action as a parameter in the form too. Now I have two options:

```
<button type="submit" name="action[enable]" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></button>
<button type="submit" name="action[delete]" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"></button>
```

or

```
<button type="submit" name="action[<?php echo $item->id; ?>]" value="enable"></button>
<button type="submit" name="action[<?php echo $item->id; ?>]" value="delete"></button>
```

Conditions:

- I'd like to *not* rely on JavaScript to do anything for me, so no 'onclick set two different hidden inputs values' please
- I'd like to use this method where I'm kinda saying `action=delete, id=3` somehow in one key=>value pair, but of course if there's a better way then do let me know

So, my questions:

- What's the best of those two options?
- Would there be any reason to go for one over the other?
- Is there something else I haven't considered?

Comment: As long as the code is working, then both the options should be fine although the 2nd option looks better as you will have to write less code in it. The 2nd option can also be easily extended later if you want to add more actions. Is the code working when you try the 2nd option? You might want to consider input validation and sanitization to prevent against XSS and SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Both will work fine, I'm just wondering if 1) there's a better way and 2) if not, which of these is better. I'm actually leaning more towards the first option as it still semantically fits in with the key/value system: it's like saying `action[specifically delete]'s id is: {id}` And yeah escaping and XSS stuff is all good - as I said, I've simplified this code for the point of demonstration, but suffice it to say I'm all good on that front.

Comment: These methods are as good as it gets if you want to use pure PHP (no AJAX/JavaScript). You will have name conflicts (in both the methods) if there are more than one item on a page that you want to edit/delete.

Comment: you can maybe give unique names to your button elements by giving them names like $item->id."_".$action and then completely remove the value fields. Then on the page where you are processing the form, you can split the input name on underscore (_) to get the item id and action in an array for further processing.

Comment: @Maximus2012 thanks for the answers, I had considered doing it through a naming convention where I can split the field names, but again it felt somewhat unsemantic. Well I think we've answered the question, anyway - either will work and there's no better way. Bummer.